# How could I import AngularFirestoreModule correctly?

Tags: angular, firebase, api, google-cloud-firestore, import

[import problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiiox.png)

I've tried to import AngularFirestoreModule but it doesn't want to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module is [exported](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/b34b2188356c93cf3ad2a9495d145927a2a79ede/docs/firestore/offline-data.md?plain=1#L16) by `@angular/fire/compat/firestore`, so:

```js
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
```